# Ionic bug (Cannot get /)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, get

I looked at a large part of the topics available on stackoverflow, but I am still stuck.

I am having a problem with Ionic. I have a page in my application which should display the information of an article according to an id communicated in the url. My system works fine when I use the command: ionic serve

But when I use: ionic cordova run browser unable to get this page I got this error showing: Cannot GET / displays / 1

I am waiting for your help, thank you very much!

Comment: Can you give an example of the routing logic of your application and the requested route ?

Answer (score 1):

Is there an error message at the console? Could you please give us more details?
I would also like to encourage you to build the project. Sometimes, build provides error messages that ionic serve does not...

Answer (score 1):

I also had a lot of problems with this error! It can come from several places from what I understand. In my case, the message in the chrome console was the following:

Refused to load the image because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

and the WEB page simply displayed the message: Cannot Get /

there were still errors in my code but my IDE doesn't display them when I run "ionic serve". To solve the problem I did a build ("ionic build") and fixed the displayed problems.
I hope this answer will help :)